# tirar os valores de uma array em xml

Tags: c#, xml

Boa tarde,

Eu gostaria de saber como adicionar os valores de uma array em xml para uma combox.

Eu estou a usar este codigo mas esta-me a dar o seguinte erro: "System.Collections.ArrayList" na  combox

c#:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Work\\tip.xml");
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            XmlNode idNodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("colors/color");
            foreach (XmlNode node1 in idNodes.ChildNodes)
                list.Add(node1.InnerText);
                comboBox1.Text = list.ToString();

        }
```

XML:

```
<colors>
    <color>
        <c1>Black</c1>
        <c2>Yellow</c2>
        <c3>White</c3>
    </color>
</colors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que você está usando windows forms. Seu problema está na lógica do seu for. Você está adicionando um item a sua lista e então tentando parsear ela totalmente para a sua combobox. Uma outra coisa, não é com o .text que se preenche a listagem do combobox. Segue o exemplo:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Work\\tip.xml");
            //ArrayList list = new ArrayList();  isso aqui não precisa
            XmlNode idNodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("colors/color");
            foreach (XmlNode node1 in idNodes.ChildNodes)
                //list.Add(node1.InnerText);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(node1.InnerText);

        }
```

Comment: obrigado era mesmo isso. Ja ha muito tempo andava atras desta soluçao.